# How to Render Two Components Conditionally?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

How can I render these two components conditionally?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, Card, CardItem, Text, Body } from 'native-base';
export default class CardHeaderFooterExample extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <Card>
        <CardItem header>
          <Text>NativeBase</Text>
        </CardItem>
        <CardItem>
          <Body>
            <Text>
              //Your text here
            </Text>
          </Body>
        </CardItem>
        <CardItem footer>
          <Text>GeekyAnts</Text>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
```

lets say:

```js
if logedin={true}
  return  
    <Card>
      <CardItem header>
        <Text>NativeBase</Text>
      </CardItem>
      <CardItem>
        <Body>
          <Text>
            //Your text here
          </Text>
        </Body>
      </CardItem>
      <CardItem footer>
        <Text>GeekyAnts</Text>
      </CardItem>
    </Card>

else return 

  <Text> signup to access this content </Text>
```

How can be this conditional rendering be done for this situation? Those components should be rendered based on boolean `logedin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is

```js
return logedin==true ? (
  <Card>
    <CardItem header>
      <Text>NativeBase</Text>
    </CardItem>
    <CardItem>
      <Body>
        <Text>
          //Your text here
        </Text>
      </Body>
    </CardItem>
    <CardItem footer>
      <Text>GeekyAnts</Text>
    </CardItem>
  </Card>
) : (
  <Text> signup to access this content </Text>
)
```

remember change to `this.props.logedin` or `this.state.logedin` if they're belong to props or state.

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible:

```
return (
    { logedin && <YourComponentWhenLogedinIsTrue/> }
    { ! logedin && <YourComponentWhenLogedinIsFalse/> }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by referring below:

```
render() {
  var1 =
    <Card>
      <CardItem header>
        <Text>NativeBase</Text>
      </CardItem>
      <CardItem>
        <Body>
          <Text>
            //Your text here
          </Text>
        </Body>
      </CardItem>
      <CardItem footer>
        <Text>GeekyAnts</Text>
      </CardItem>
    </Card>

var2 = <Text> signup to access this content </Text>

return(
  <View>
  {logedin == true
     ? var1
     : var2
  }
  </View>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in multiple ways.

- Using multiple **returns**

  ```
  render()
  {
    if(!logedin){
      return <Text> Signup to access this content </Text>;
    }

    return( <CardComponent/> );
  }
  ```
- Using ternary operator

> condition ? statement to execute if condition is **true** : statement to execute if condition is **false**

```
    render()
    {
       return islogedin ? <CardComponent/> : <Text> Signup to access this content </Text>;
    }
```